# WordPress, allow certain users to view certain pages

Tags: php, wordpress, restriction

I have a WP site where each page hosts a video course. Whenever a customer buys a course (offline, through my company) I have to make his WP user able to see the page with the video of that course.

I tried many plugins, but all of them refer to user levels and roles, which are suboptimal for my purpose because I have to deal with one user at the time, and I want to avoid the password system.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you the steps of how to do it.
VIP customer is a customer who buys the course
1)Create a new row in your phpMyAdmin table, with type boolean and name, VIP
2) When you store VIP customers details, insert in the table with VIP as true.
3) When he visits the page, keep an sql statement which fetches his record by his ID and checks is VIP is 1, if it is, display some content, if he is not, take him to another page.

Comment: Thank you, But does't that make the user able to view all the videos? I'm a novice of php and I'd like to try with plugins first...